# SSD performance on Windows better than on Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, sata

I hope someone can give me a hint about where to look for. My Crucial MX300 750MB is performing a lot better on Windows than on Linux and I can't find out why. These are the results:

- **Windows: 533 MB/s** max read speed
  [CrystalDiskMark 8.0.0 benchmark results of Crucial_CT750MX300SSD1 /dev/sdb6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULT1o.png)
- **Linux: 346 MB/s** max read speed

```
~$ hdparm -Ttv /dev/sdb6

/dev/sdb6:
multcount     =  0 (off)
IO_support    =  1 (32-bit)
readonly      =  0 (off)
readahead     = 256 (on)
geometry      = 25665/255/63, sectors = 127432704, start = 83892224
Timing cached reads:   16474 MB in  1.99 seconds = 8269.94 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 1038 MB in  3.00 seconds = 345.86 MB/sec
~$ hdparm -V
hdparm v9.58
```

```
~$ smartctl -d ata -x /dev/sdb | grep "SATA\|Firmware"
Firmware Version: M0CR070  # <-- latest firmware
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
```

```
~$ lspci -nnk
SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T520 [17aa:21cf]
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
```

```
~$ dmesg
[    1.917727] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    1.920398] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    1.920405] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.920409] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    1.920772] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    1.921965] ata2.00: ATA-10: Crucial_CT750MX300SSD1,  M0CR070, max UDMA/133
[    1.921971] ata2.00: 1465149168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    1.926973] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    1.926980] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    1.926984] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    1.927288] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    1.930516] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.941605] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
```

```
~$ uname -r
5.8.0-40-generic
```

```
~$ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler 
[mq-deadline] none
```

---

The same disk was measured to 485 MB/sec using hdparm [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844459/ubuntu-ssd-was-fast-is-now-extremely-slow):

> ```
> lptp [ ~ ]: sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
>
> /dev/sda: Timing cached reads:   12388 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6197.19
> MB/sec Timing buffered disk reads: 1454 MB in  3.00 seconds = 484.59
> MB/sec
> ```

So it doesn't seem to be about hdparm not being comparable to CrystalDiskMark. I also tested with the latest Debian live iso as well as with Ubuntu 16.04.7 iso and installed the 5.10.10 mainline kernel. Same hdparm results.

So, at the moment the following can be rooted out as cause of the difference in performance:

- the SSD
- the power management
- my linux installation
- probably the kernel too

EDIT:

I found this [old post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812304/sandisk-ssd-plus-half-the-performance-on-linux-than-on-windows#) of mine where the same disk was performing way better on linux and on the same laptop... I don't know what's going on here... I just tested the SSD with the same program on Windows and [the results are the same as back then!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XMkY.png)

EDIT 2:
Updated the BIOS. No change.

EDIT 3:
On a live iso of Ubuntu 16.04.1 hdparm measures different values!

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   15580 MB in  2.00 seconds = 7795.60 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1308 MB in  3.00 seconds = 435.76 MB/sec
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ hdparm -V
hdparm v9.48
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-31-generic
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

EDIT 4: It's the kernel!!

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -r
4.9.253-0409253-generic
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -Ttv /dev/sdb
[...]
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1302 MB in  3.00 seconds = 433.43 MB/sec
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -r
4.10.0-041000rc1-generic
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hdparm -Ttv /dev/sdb
[...]
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1028 MB in  3.01 seconds = 342.02 MB/sec
```

Everything else in the test system was kept equal. If it's a kernel bug it has been there since 4.10. I'll file a report on bugzilla and hope someone takes the time for it.

Comment: Why would CrystalDiskMark be comparable to hdparm?  Are they using the same size I/Os?  Same queue depth?  Same buffer sizes?

Comment: @stark Because both are disk benchmark tools that output results with the same performance unit (MB/s). And also because the results of hdparm should be somewhere near the manufaturers specs, like it is the case for CrystalDiskMark. The other questions I cannot answer.

Comment: @stark Same disk delivered `Timing buffered disk reads: 1454 MB in  3.00 seconds = 484.59 MB/sec` from hdparm [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844459/ubuntu-ssd-was-fast-is-now-extremely-slow).

Comment: Good link! You're on a laptop, so Power Mgmt is active.  A thorough disk benchmark will probably turn that off, but hdparm is a diagnostic tool, not really a benchmark.

Comment: @stark My laptop is on AC. I disabled the power management and restarted -> no change :/

Comment: +1 for interesting, well written question and doing your own research. Please post an answer once you're satisfied with your findings and I'll happily upvote it. (self-answering [is fine](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer))